# Run action/script AFTER the binary executed by "bazel run" returns

Tags: bazel

I'm wondering if there's a way to run an action or script or program *after* a `bazel run` command finishes. Running such a script/program *before* the bazel run is (in a way) possible via `--run_under`.

Here's an example use-case:

1. `bazel run //path/to/my:target`
2. Running `target` generates an output file `out` in it's `cwd` (somewhere in the bazel `.cache` directory)
3. Run a script that uses the output file `out`

If it's not possible to get run that script afterwards, is there a way to get the `cwd` of the binary that was just run? Then it would also be possible to access `out` from "outside" without bazel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--run_under` is the correct approach to this. You can simply run the command in the script after running what is passed as args to your script that you pass to `--run_under` e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

./prefix_command

bash "$@"

./postfix_command
```